# How to solve personal library problem in r

Tags: r

I am a hardworking beginner in r and I have some problems.
Hope to get some help from amazing experts in this site!!
Recently I am having some problems with installing packages in r.
I removed r and also the paths of library and reinstalled, but that didn't help.
Instead this

```
would you like to use a personal library instead message?
```

is keep showing.
I want to know what should I do in this situation.
Thank you in advance and hope everyone's day goes well. :)

Comment: Not exactly sure what your goal is - just getting things to install, or wanting to set up a personal library? Do you have any reason to want a personal library rather than the standard library location? When does this message show up? What is the result of `.libPaths()`?

Comment: First of all thanks for giving a hand! I just want to install packages right..and this message shows up when I command 'install.packages("doBy"). And the result of .libPaths() is "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R tells you where it can install: do `.libPaths()` to see.  It is telling you that for *all* directories therein *you do not* have write permissions.

Which is why it offers to create a 'personal library'.  I usually recommend going the other way and *e.g.* adding the user to the group owning the main library directory.  On my Linux systems that is `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`.

Comment: Dirk, interesting point about encouraging loosening perms (a skosh) on `/usr/local/...`. Disk space (and bandwidth) is generally cheap-enough these days that having two (or more) copies of the same-version package in different locations is not *that* costly, is your preference towards space efficiency? (I'm not talking about project-oriented package-version control, which is generally a different discussion that brings `packrat`, `rev`, and `checkpoint`.) Thanks!

Comment: I'll say that my linux-R experience is typically not really multi-user, so my exposure is much different than yours (I'm not supposing my experience is the same as yours, on multiple levels).

Comment: Actually, not loosening perms. Adding to group. One this system (where I type) "my" account is a member of group `staff` so I can write to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` which is group-write and group `staff`.  It's a bit of a tricky topic but I have written about it here in a few answers over the years.  (And I don't care about double space etc but I *do* care about one consistent installation for all uses, scripts, cron jobs, ...)

Comment: I think "consistent" is what I was looking for. I'm comfortable enough with the group/sticky-bit conversation; I was coarsely considering "adding user to a group" to be the little "loosening", which is a stretch, admittedly. Thanks.

Comment: We're on the same page then. (Also, that may just be me, I prefer to keep libraries in that directory in order. Which has worked for ~25 years, so no need for `renv` or `packrat` or `checkpoint` here....)

Comment: I'm surprised, I can only imagine with a disparate collection of clients and projects, maintaining projects with major (semantic) dep-pkg upgrades to require work to update. Even assuming that unit-testing is near 100% coverage, the major version shift (again, in semantic versioning) is expressly for a reason, so even honest updates for one project will have secondary impacts on another. Don't get me wrong, I don't use `renv`/`packrat` as religiously as they suggest, but ... I do run into dep-pkg update problems across my dozen or so (private) packages, and it sometimes hurts.